# Request was pending in chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, tomcat

When request my website，It was normal at first, but after a period of time, the request was always pending.

But another environment with the same code is normal. Could it be a server problem?

I have captured some information using net-export. it was stuck on SOCKET_POOL_STALLED_MAX_SOCKETS_PER_GROUP

[image]
[image]
[image]
Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Did you manage to find the reason why it did this ? I'm having the same problem on Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP/1.x** allows only [six active/parallel connections](https://hpbn.co/http1x/#using-multiple-tcp-connections) so try to debug your network request and look which request may hang up. For example some websocket libs may fall back on long polling and this may be the reason. But now it's better to move on [**HTTP/2** which kind of solve problem of six connections](https://hpbn.co/http2/#request-and-response-multiplexing)